# Deployment of ASP.Net Project via awsdeploy does not really copy files to instance

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I deploy my ASP.Net project to elastic beanstalk via awsdeploy it says everything is working fine. However no files actually make it to the instance.

There are no errors in the logs (event or EC2 or EBS).

I've tried zip package deployment and incremental and neither seem to add anything to the instance.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try looking at the logs using Snapshot log functionality: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html

Comment: @RohitBanga The logs don't seem to write to S3. I'm looking in my /elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-XXX/resources/environments/e-XXX/ folders and I don't have folder other than runtime.

My Events show : Pulled logs for environment instances. and Deleted log fragments for this environment. I've looked in all the S3 folders and buckets and nothing.

Comment: There is nothing in the event logs on these machines either. Very strange.

Comment: I can recommend another tutorial for creating a .Net app: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.sdlc.html
Does this help? I am not sure what your development workflow is like?

Comment: Workflow is an empty project in VS2013. My project does not deploy. even after setting the web app to "Default Web Site".
Issue is that my web deploy package deploys fine via awsdeploy, but the files do not make it on to the instance.

Comment: @RohitBanga I followed the same document and I have the same issue. My files do not make it to the instance. I've looked in every folder on the instance. Very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem where it was not deploying to the stack and not displaying any errors.  What I found was that I was trying to deploy my code to an unsupported AWS platform.

i.e. .Net v4.5.1 is not currently supported on IIS 7.5 or 8.0

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.platforms.html#concepts.platforms.net

Hope this helps

Comment: Even if I modified the AMI image to have 4.5.1?

Comment: I ended up just lowering my framework version in the project to 4.5 and all is well...except it's not what I wanted to do.